# PHP search string with exceptions

Tags: php, string, search, str-replace

I'm trying to use PHP to search a string for individual letters and replace it with a bold letters. I created a function to do this which is below:

```
function matchText($key,$before){
  $search = str_split($key);
  $after = $before;
  foreach($search as $s){
    $s1 = strtolower($s);
    $r1 = "<b>".$s1."</b>";
    $s2 = strtoupper($s);
    $r2 = "<b>".$s2."</b>";
    $after = str_replace($s1, $r1, $after);
    $after = str_replace($s2, $r2, $after);
    $after = str_replace("</b><b>","",$after);
  }
  return $after;
}
```

I pass in the search string ($key) and the full string to search ($before).
It splits the search string into individual characters to search for and for each character it checks both the lower case and upper case versions and replaces it with a bold version. Finally it gets rid of any connecting HTML < b > tags so I don't end up with a string full of tags.

The problem is when the search string contains a "b" and it replaces all "b"s including the ones in the HTML < b > tags which creates messed up strings.

For example I'm searching a list of names for Fred Campbell and using the search string "campb" I get a result string of:

[image: Messed up string from Chrome Dev tools]

When what I want to get as a result is "Fred **Campb**ell"

Is there a way to create an exception in the search not to replace the letter "b" if it is surronded by < > or < / >?

Or maybe a different way of doing this?

EDIT:

This is part of an ajax call which queries a database of names as the user types in a text field. As they type a dropdown list of up to 10 results is given with the search string highlighted in the original string. 
So for example, my database has 2 names "Fred Campbell" and "Andrew Flycamp" (random name :P). If the user types "camp" the dropdown list will contain both names with each character of the search string in bold and in their original case.

So "Fred Campbell" becomes "Fred **Camp**bell" and "Andrew Flycamp" becomes "**A**ndrew Fly**camp**"

Notice the upper case in "Campbell" and the lower case in "Flycamp". This should happen even if I search "CAMP" or "Camp" or "camp".

My code does this fine right up until a "b" is added to the search string and things get weird and bold tags get messed up beyond recognition.

Comment: yes there is use preg_replace() with regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a character class and replace the matched characters by reference `\0`.

```
<?php

function matchText($text, $key) {
  return preg_replace('/['.$key.']/i', '<b>\0</b>', $text);
}

$text = 'Andrew Flycamp';

//<b>A</b>ndrew Fly<b>c</b><b>a</b><b>m</b><b>p</b>
echo matchText($text, 'camp');
```

https://eval.in/367653

Answer (score 3):

there is a simpler way to do it :

```
function matchText($text, $key) {
  return preg_replace('#'.$key.'#i', '<b>'.$key.'</b>',$text);
}

$text = 'Fred Campbell';

echo matchText($text, 'camp');
```

That will return :

```
Fred <b>Camp</b>bell
```

Comment: The `g` modifier is invalid with php `preg_replace`

Comment: My bad. Didn't know (but it's logical).

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Means that 2 people upV it without even knowing anything about the code

Comment: Albeit a small mistake, answers *should* be logical and supply the correct code. I was the second upvote as it was a simple mistake and quickly amended.

Comment: Shouldn't `'<b>&1</b>'`be `'<b>'.$key.'</b>'` ?

Comment: Although this works, with adjustments, the reason I was splitting the search string into individual characters was so that if I searched "camp" it would return "<b>Camp</b>". Notice the lower case "c" in the search and the upper case "C" in the result. I thought the "i" modifier dealt with this but its not doing what I expected. Thanks for the logic though, I'll mess around with it to see if I can get it exactly how I need.

Comment: @jakecfc1992 change the `preg_replace` with `preg_replace('#('.$key.')#i', '<b>\1</b>',$text);`. This will create a capture group so you can reference it in the replace. - https://eval.in/367638

Comment: ^ This seems to have worked exactly how I needed it to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345964/3000179) is nice, it's flawed in a way that you cannot use this for words, as it will replace part words with bold text.

I'd suggest doing the following change.

```php
function matchText($text, $key, $blFullWord = TRUE) {
  if( $blFullWord ) {
     //We want to match the full word and not part-word
     return preg_replace('#\b('.$key.')\b#i', '<b>\1</b>',$text);
  }
  return preg_replace('#('.$key.')#i', '<b>\1</b>',$text);
}

$text = 'Fred Campbell was camping in a camp during the night';

//Fred Campbell was camping in a <b>camp</b> during the night
echo matchText($text, 'camp');
//Fred <b>Camp</b>bell was <b>camp</b>ing in a <b>camp</b> during the night
echo matchText($text, 'camp', FALSE);
```

https://eval.in/367640

**Notice 2 things;**

- The capture group on the word we want to replace which allows us to reference it in the replace - meaning we keep the case.
- The word boundaries. This means it will match the full word, and not sub-word, for example `<b>Camp</b>ing`.

Comment: Hmm, I should have probably provided a little background to this. See this is part of an ajax call which uses the string to query a database of names and returns up to 10 results in a dropdown menu. The menu contains the names with the search string in bold. The user might only know a partial of the name, "campb", and when they type the dropdown should list the results and highlight the search characters in the full original string (if you know what I mean). I will edit my question to include this

Comment: Edited my original question to include more background. See I need it to replace both partial and full words in bold text. I'm thinking that my issue can't be solved with pre_replace but instead custom changes if the letter "b" is found in the search string.

Comment: I've [added another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30347717/3000179) to address your edits.

Comment: Just noticed your comment on the other answer, that seems to be the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @jakecfc1992 great news :) *Cheers!*